# django db ProgrammingError

Tags: django, django-models

When i try to reset database (i created a new empty database)

i got this error when i run this command `python manage.py` makemigrations (or migrate)

```
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File \python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "project\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    path('api/v2/', include('project.api.urls'), name='api'),
  File "django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "project\api\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "project\api\views.py", line 146, in <module>
    class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "project\api\views.py", line 148, in SampleViewSet
    general = General.objects.get(is_active=True)
  File "django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django\db\models\query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "django\db\models\query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
        django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: HATA:  "app_general" object doesnt exist
    LINE 1: ...", "app_general"."field1" FROM "field_2...
```

views.py

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    general = General.objects.get(is_active=True)
    queryset = model.objects.filter(field=site_general.field)
```

i deleted all migration files in all apps (without  `__init__` ) and also .pyc files

is there any idea for this problem?

(edit i added Traceback)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    general = General.objects.get(is_active=True)
    queryset = model.objects.filter(field=site_general.field) `

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i added

Comment: What is `site_general` in `model.objects.filter(field=site_general.field)`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I do not think views.py will cause problems because I changed the database many times but now there is a problem and I did not change views.py and that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the non-method attributes of a class get evaluated /executed during the declaration or definition of the class. Hence when the interpreter reaches your class `SampleViewSet` it tries to execute the line `general = General.objects.get(is_active=True)` but of course your database doesn't exist yet and since calling `.get` implies a database query you get an error.

In general any statement that might cause a database query should be either run by the app configs `ready` method, by some middleware / context processor, or by the view in a request. Looking at the code it doesn't look like you use `general` anywhere, so you can simply remove it:

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = model.objects.filter(field=site_general.field)
```

You might say `model.objects.filter(...)` would also cause a query, but `.filter` returns a `QuerySet` and queryset's are lazy and hence evaluated only when needed, so that will not cause any error.

Comment: I got it on the comment line and it worked, but it was a strange experience. Thanks for help